# Urban airship - App updates using in app messages

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I have new version of android app in Playstore, Am using urban airship for in app messages and push notifications. How do i send an app update of new version to users as an in app message for users which they have old version of app .?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean sending an in-app message to notify the old app users of the new update, then you can do that by the following:

- Create a new message
- From the AUDIENCE tab select "Target Specific Users"
- Click the arrow next to the search field and select "Android App Version"
- type the old app version, and select it from the drop down list.
- Continue the in-app message setup as normal

If you mean triggering the actual app update, then I don't think that UA has this functionality out of the box.

references:
 - https://docs.urbanairship.com/engage/target-specific-users/#tsu-dev-props